# Set multiple targets with turbo form submission in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-rails

I have a response that has a template with 3 different turbo_tags nested in another one.

```
= turbo_frame_tag 'container'
  = turbo_frame_tag 'frame1'
    = form_with url: path, data: { turbo_frame: '?' }
  = turbo_frame_tag 'frame2'
  = turbo_frame_tag 'frame3'
```

I want my form submission to render the same view and update the frame1 and frame3 to get updated but not the frame2. Is that possible? what should I set on turbo_frame attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can target multiple frames by id - but you can use the `targets` attribute with a CSS selector. https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/streams#targeting-multiple-elements

Comment: That CSS selector can be a list of ids "#frame1, #frame2" or you can add classes to the frames you want to target.

Comment: currently it can't be done you need to target _top and replace them all, https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/56#issuecomment-752632522
and https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/475